# Asymptotic results for smallest gap of Gaussian random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

For a symmetric Gaussian random matrix $G=\{G\}_{1\le i,j \le n}$ with iid $E[G_{ij}]=0$ and $E[G_{ij}^2]=1/n$ (it is normalized), ordering its eigenvalues $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le\cdots \lambda_n$.

Is there any results about the asymptotic result for the smallest gap $\delta=\min_{1\le i,j \le n}\{|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a complex Hermitian matrix (GUE ensemble) the probability distribution of the smallest eigenvalue spacing $\delta_{\rm min}$ is such that the rescaled minimal spacing $x=\delta_{\rm min}n^{4/3}$ has for large $n$ the asymptotic distribution
$$P(x)=3x^2e^{-x^3},$$
see [Closest Spacing of Eigenvalues](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2743) by J.P. Vinson (2011).

This result has been generalized to real symmetric matrices (GOE ensemble) by Feng, Tian, and Wei, in [Small gaps of GOE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.01567) (2019). In  that case the rescaled minimal spacing $x=\delta_{\rm min}n^{3/2}$ has for large $n$ the limiting distribution
$$P(x)=2xe^{-x^2}.$$

Note that for independent eigenvalues (with a mean spacing that scales as $1/n$) the minimal spacing would scale as $n^{-2}$ (Poisson distribution). The $n^{-3/2}$ scaling for the GOE and the $n^{-4/3}$ scaling for the GUE are indicative of "level repulsion" (stronger for the GUE than for the GOE). More generally, for the three classical ensembles (GOE: $\beta=1$, GUE: $\beta=2$, GSE: $\beta=4$) the minimal spacing scales as $n^{-(\beta+2)/(\beta+1)}$, and the rescaled minimal spacing has limiting distribution $P(x)\propto x^\beta e^{-x^{\beta+1}}$.

<sub>In the OP the scaling $\delta_{\rm min} n^{2/3}\log n$ is suggested, I don't know where that comes from, it does not agree with these results from the literature, the scaling should be $\delta_{\rm min} n^{3/2}$ in the GOE. Note also that, since the mean level spacing scales as $1/n$, the smallest spacing cannot have an exponent smaller than $1$ -- a scaling as $n^{-2/3}$ is not possible.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! If we do not consider the smallest gap. So this result also holds for $\lambda_2-\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_n-\lambda_1$?

Comment: Can I ask the meaning of this convergence rate of $\delta_{\min}$? Does it mean $\delta_{\min} n^{3/2}=O_p(1)$?

Comment: Also, in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1294. In page 6, it says that $n^{2/3}(\lambda_n-2, .., \lambda_{n-k}) \to $a multivariate Tracy–Widom distribution as $n\to \infty$. So it seems that $n^{2/3}(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)=O_p(1)$. I am confused about this result. Does it contradict with $\delta_{\min} n^{3/2}=O_p(1)$?

Comment: the Tracy-Widom distribution refers to eigenvalues near the edge of the spectrum; the spacing is much larger there than in the bulk; you asked for the smallest spacing; that is in the bulk of the spectrum, not at the edge.

Comment: Thanks! But I am not very familiar with concepts like `edge of the spectrum` and `bulk`. So you mean $\delta_{\min}=O_(n^{-3/2})$ is much smaller than $\lambda_2-\lambda_1=O_p(n^{-2/3})$? I also add some details for the asymptotic bound for $\lambda_2-\lambda_1$.

Comment: Tracy-Widom is really irrelevant for your question; if you order them from small to large, only the first few and the last few are governed by Tracy-Widom, they have a mean spacing of order $n^{-2/3}$;  this is called the "edge" of the spectrum; the other eigenvalues, so the vast majority of them, have a mean spacing of order $n^{-1}$ and a smallest spacing of order $n^{-3/2}$; this is called the 'bulk" of the spectrum.